# Is it possible to register an amazon route 53 domain name without having your name and address on public display?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I would like to register a domain name with route 53, Only I want to prevent people from seeing my name and address when they use a service like `whois lookup` (http://whois.domaintools.com/). With Godaddy you can choose to keep the name and address details private. Is this possible when registering a domain with route 53 as well?

Also, when registering a domain name with Amazon you also get a `hosted zone` to configure DNS settings with. This hosted zone costs 0,50$ a month but your free to delete it if you want to avoid the charge. I do not plan to use my domain name immediately after having purchased it. If I delete the hosted zone, can I recreate it at a later point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This protection usually has a generic name like "WhoIs Guard" or "Domain Privacy".

Amazon's is called [Privacy Protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-privacy-protection.html) and is enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

As for this bit...

> If I delete the hosted zone, can I recreate it at a later point in time?

Yes, you can. You'll get a new set of nameservers, which you'll need to adjust the domain to point at, but that's just a minute of tweaking.

Comment: Ah yeah I missed this part of the question. That's what happens when you roll two questions into one I guess.